# How to make this 'overflowing rigid bodies' effect?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I saw this cool effect in the 2022 Reddit Recap video:

[image: still frame of motion graphics video]

As you can see in the [video here](https://vimeo.com/792178495#t=7s), there's a cool 'overflowing' effect going on that I'm not entirely sure how to achieve (I'm trying to make a video) - maybe particles spawning from inside the container with rigid body physics?

Any opinions / ideas / wild speculation welcomed.

Thanks,

Andy

Edit - seems the original video link doesn't work for some - it's made by a company called toast, and you'll find the video on their [page here](https://toast.tv/reddit-recap-2022).

- Also edited to clarify I'm trying to make a video, not a still frame.

Comment: Hello, I can't see the video, do you want to animate or is it for a still image? Particles can't be rigid body, and it's probably better to use rigid body for the image you show (with a bunch of object falling into the cylinder but maybe your animation is different)

Comment: I cannot see the video either. Are those objects coming upwards from the bottom of the glas?

Comment: Hmmm, that's odd - it's a standard Vimeo link, not sure what I've done wrong. I'll edit the post to include a link to the video on the creator's page. I'm trying to create a video with the effect, apologies if that part wasn't clear.

Comment: @Andy the Vimeo video is "unrated" and therefore requires a login. So you can't just watch it if you don't have an account. The second link works :-)

Comment: Ah, that explains it - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Just add a cylinder, delete top face, give it solidify modifier + rigid body passive - shape: mesh
2. copy the bottom face -> P -> selection -> scale it down a bit -> apply scale -> rigid body -> active
3. now add an object (should be simple, else the RB simulation will take a loooong time), make it rigid body active, shape: mesh
4. double the object many times above cylinder, rotate a bit so they will fall "randomly"
5. let the simulation run

5b) with object -> rigid body -> apply visual transformation you can
"fix" the objects in the bin

6. repeat step 3-6 until the cylinder is full
7. animate the object 2 on z axis up

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic, exactly what I wanted. When you put it like that it seems kind of obvious, but I didn't think of it, so yeah. Thanks for the effort, really appreciate it!

Comment: you are welcome